# Assign a hierarchical path to a string variable inside generate block for N number of instances

Tags: for-loop, system-verilog

I want to assign a hierarchical path to a string variable inside a `generate` block for N number of instances.
Please let me know if it can work. I'm getting errors for hier assignment.

```
xmvlog: *E,EXPLPA (testbench.sv,17|9): expecting a left parenthesis ('(') [12.1.2][7.1(IEEE)].
      sub.str = `STRINGIFY(`HPATH);
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
module test;
  
`define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"
`define HPATH top.chip.block
    subtest sub[3]();
  string hpath;
  
  initial begin
    hpath = `STRINGIFY(`HPATH);
    $display("HPATH is %s", hpath);
  end
  genvar r;
  generate
    for (r=0;r<2;r++)begin
      sub[r].str = `STRINGIFY(`HPATH);
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule

module subtest();
  string str;
  initial begin
    $display("%s",str);
  end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment you are trying to make is a procedural assignment, which means it must be inside a procedural block, like `initial`:

```
for (r=0;r<2;r++)begin
    initial sub[r].str = `STRINGIFY(`HPATH);
end
```

To avoid a race condition and guarantee that you will see the assigned string value in the `subtest` module, add some delay to the `$display`:

```
  initial begin
      #1 $display("%s",str);
  end
```